# JSONArray object to jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, arrays

In my Java code I have a JSONArray object, named colorList which contains a list of colors. It looks something like this:
    ["Red", "Yellow", "Blue"]

How do I pass this value to a jquery variable?

My jquery should look like this:

```
var hooks = {  
   processOptions: [function(plot,options) {  
           options.colors = ["Red", "Yellow", "Blue"];
   }]  
 };
```

Comment: What is `jQuery variable` ?

Comment: You can make an ajax call to server and return the JSON Array of colors as response, and use it in your client side JS code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `.get` ajax call which can receive a JSON.

```
    $.get('YourServlet', {varTest: 'Test'}, function (response) {

            var jSON = JSON.parse(response);  });// varTest if you want to pass some values once you have the JSON you can get the inside data.
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` in JSON2 documentation

**Syntax:**

```
myData = JSON.parse(text); // from json string to js object

var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(myObject, replacer); // js object to json string
```

**Code Snippet:**

Use below piece of code after AJAX return function.

```
var myData = JSON.parse(text);

String val = '';

for (var i = 0; i < options.colors.length; i++){
   val = myData.options.colors[i] + ",";
}

if (val .indexOf(",") != -1){
    val = val .substring(0, val .length-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to do something like this:

Set up your initial object:

```
var hooks = {
   processOptions: []
};
```

Create a function that we will use late that returns a new function that sets the `colors` key of the object that's passed into it:

```
function createFunction(data) {
  return function (plot, options) {
     options.colors = data;
  }
}
```

Grab your color array data from the server, create a new function using that data, and push it to the `hooks.processOptions` array:

```
$.get(endpoint).then(function (data) {

    // var data = ["Red", "Yellow", "Blue"];
    var options = {};
    var plot = null;  

    hooks.processOptions.push(createFunction(data));

    // you can then call that function with the arguments you need
    hooks.processOptions[0](plot, options);
});
```

You can see in this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n94xjzy4/1/) that when the function is called it logs the array to the console.